# MVC 5 and my own select

Tags: c#, oracle, model-view-controller

Working with existing systems (Oracle database) sometimes I need to create model's from procedures that return tables. Is this possible? Does anyone have a code sample using any database?

Comment: maybe you can consider an ORM like EntityFramwork, NHibernate

Comment: Good idea; I will try and will leave some comment here. Thank you.